# very strange file permission and read/write error

Tags: permissions, mount

I try to read a folder on my secondary hdd but I can't access to one folder. when i try a `ll` command in parent folder, my "html_archive" folder have very strange permition (`????????`). if I try `ll html_archive`, I've this error : `ls: impossible d'accéder à '/media/agenceho5/Docs/html_archive': Erreur d'entrée/sortie` (in english : "Unable to access /media/agenceho5/Doc/html_archive : input/output error)
[image]

I've tried to repair partition but same error...

any idea ?

thanks !

Comment: Repair partition with `fsck`?

Comment: Can you access the folder from a live system?

Comment: What is the used file-system, is this a NTFS partition?

Comment: fsck just return `fsck de util-linux 2.31.1` and nothing else. I've tried with a Windows10 system (in dualboot on my computer) and can't access folder. The partition is NTFS (in disk utility, it's said `NTFS/exFAT/HPFS`)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command (through `sudo` or more probably from `su`):

```
chown -R root:root html_archive && chmod 7## html_archive
```

Where ## are your preferred permissions for user and other, respectively.

Comment: same error when I launch this commands `chown: impossible d'accéder à 'html_archive': Erreur d'entrée/sortie`

Comment: Even with sudo or as root?

Comment: yes, even with sudo